# Question in on-hold: Was it blocked? Nobody can answer it after a edit?

Tags: support, questions, on-hold

I am a beginner in these stack-like communities. I have posted my [first question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/77371) on Stack Security, and people marked it as "on hold," for being "unclear what you're asking."

I have seen the error and fixed it. But, I have a big question: Is "on hold" the same as being blocked question? Can somebody answer the question now? The moderator has not removed the on-hold tag.

I have edited it. I think that it is right, now. But the on-hold tag still there.

Can I delete it and post a new question? Must I wait for a moderator reply?

Comment: This question? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77371/stack-buffer-overflow-is-compiler-changing-variables-order-preventing-me-to-ov

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvotted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not repost your question, please!

To make sure the problem was really fixed, the question will remain on hold until a moderator reviews it and decides to reopen it. If you want, you can flag your question (there's a little link under the question for that), and leave a message to the moderators, with a request to be open. (*though [Jamal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/217361/jamal) wrote in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246568/question-in-on-hold-was-it-blocked-nobody-can-answer-it-after-a-edit/246569#comment807190_246569) to this answer that "You probably shouldn't flag a question for reopening unless it was a single moderator that closed it. Even then, you can still ping that same moderator;" I agree*)

The other way for your question to be reopened is to have five users with 3,000+ reputation vote to reopen the question.

In the meantime, no one will be able to post new answers; that is correct. However, this is not the same as a question ban, which means that (for a period of time) you are not allowed to ask new questions. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/266359) for more information on question bans.

Good luck, and I hope you find an answer to your questions!

Comment: You probably shouldn't flag a question for reopening unless it was a single moderator that closed it.  Even then, you can still ping that same moderator.

Comment: @Jamal That's fair.

Comment: @Jamal Is a bad choice flag an question?? I have done it. Am I getting in troubles??? I want to preserve my account.

Comment: @DeanWinchester No, it's not a big problem. Moderators would prefer that you grab their attention by flags only when you really need to, but one bad flag won't get you suspended. I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: @DeanWinchester ....this is a case where flagging is not really needed, because after you edited your question, it automatically ends up in the "reopen vote" review queue, for 3K users to check it out, and see if they will vote to reopen the question.

Comment: @Shokhet I have done it. Has not problems for me??

Comment: @DeanWinchester No, there probably won't be any problems for you because of one bad flag.